# Where does UICollectionView etc calculate content size so that I can permanently increase it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to add a view to the bottom of the content view of both a collection view and table view (and hence is applicable to any kind of scroll view) and I also want to be able to scroll down to see this view e.g.:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Observe change in content size so can move my view when
        // content size changes (keep it at the bottom)
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"
                  options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior)
                  context:nil];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
        self.loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.loadingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self addSubview:self.loadingView];
        // Increase height of content view so that can scroll to my view.
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height+30);

    }
    return self;
}
```

However when, for example, a cell is inserted the contentSize is recalculated and whilst my view is still visible at the bottom of the content size (due to being able to bounce the scroll view) I can no longer scroll to it.

How do I ensure that the content size stays, as in my code, 30 points taller?

An additional question is:

- is there any other way to track content size other than observing it?

Thanks in advance.

---

I have tried:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height+30);
}
```

However this causes all sorts of display issues.

Comment: you may want to do these calculations in layoutSubviews.

Comment: Is this where UICollectionView etc usually calculate contentSize?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that changes the `contentSize`

Comment: Apologies you're right. Updated it. Still same issue.

Comment: UICollectionViewLayout has a method that calculates the content size. With custom layouts, it is necessary to override this method. It is not layoutSubviews though. (it could be contentSize, but overriding the getter doesn't sound correct)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to show a loading view in the tableView (f.e.) at the bottom. You could add an extra UITableViewCell containing this LoaderView to the tableView.
(Must change the numberOfRowsInTableView)

In another perspective for scrollViews: Use smaller bounds then the content itself, to make it scrollable. For example frame = fullscreen. At every cell adding or modification in subviews (adding) contentSize = content size + 30 px.

Comment: Yep this is what I have at the moment, however I have 5 instances of this across my application e.g. UITableView and UICollectionViews with loading views. I'm trying to abstract this in some way by building it into the UIxxxView itself.

Comment: It's probably possible to abstract it in the ViewController by permanently  increasing the number of cells and setting the size of the last cell, however I like the idea of having a Delegate protocol that sends a message to a receiver upon hitting a 'trigger row' and then the delegate inserting more data.

Comment: In this case: what about a category, which adds a LoaderView as a property to the UIScrollView class and an overwritten setContentSize method, which auto increase the contentSize.y with the height of the loaderView. You can find more on properties in category here: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Answer (score 0):

Try making a subclass of the scroll view and override the contentSize getter to return always 30 px more.

```
- (CGSize)contentSize {
    CGSize customContentSize = super.contentSize;
    customContentSize.height += 30;
    return customContentSize;
}
```

(I'm writing the code by memory, there may be errors)